# Is there a `$slice` like comparison for MongoDB's filters?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In MongoDB there is a [projection operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) `$slice` which allows projecting a subarray.

Is there any way to filter by an array slice as well? Something like:

```
db.testdb.find( {arrayofstring: { $eqSlice: {$slice: [0,1], $val: [ "a" ] } } }, {...})
```

**Edit:** An example and its expected output

```
> db.studentsTestDataTypes.find({},{ _id: 1, int: 1, arraystring: 1})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("56977186756088b586154f9d"), "int" : 2001, "arraystring" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56977186756088b586154f9e"), "int" : 2002, "arraystring" : [ "d", "e", "f" ] }
```

Example of expected result: Filtering by those entries with value "a" at the first position of `arraystring`:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56977186756088b586154f9d"), "int" : 2001, "arraystring" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have the following document in your collection:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56977186756088b586154f9d"), "int" : 2001, "arraystring" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56977186756088b586154f9e"), "int" : 2002, "arraystring" : [ "d", "e", "f" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56978e21ae9bb55c0d7cdc67"), "int" : 2001, "arraystring" : [ "b", "a", "c" ] }
```

The easier and best way is to use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)

```js
db.collection.find({ "arraystring.0": "a" } )
```

Which yields:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56977186756088b586154f9d"),
        "int" : 2001,
        "arraystring" : [
                "a",
                "b",
                "c"
        ]
}
```

Comment: You nailed it! It is exactly what I was looking for